# Order by on an alphanumerical column

Tags: mysql, select, order-by

I have a column that has strings of the following type:
`Miller 10`
`Allen 20`
`King 10`
....
`Jones 100`

I try to sort the column based on the numerical part of the data.
I tried the following:

`SELECT * FROM the_table ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(data,2) AS UNSIGNED);`

But this does not work. It places `Jones 100` as the first entry etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the space, then cast everything after the space

```
SELECT * FROM the_table
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTR(data,LOCATE(' ',data)+1) AS UNSIGNED);
```

Give it a Try !!!

Your query did not work because the RIGHT 2 of 100 is 00, which would be numerically first.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a built-in function for parsing texts in the form of [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).

This simplifies your query to:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,' ',-1) AS UNSIGNED);
```